# Kivy select screen in .py-file and use in .kv-file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a list of screens and randomly select one of them in this python file (other code is not included here, like builder etc):

```
class selectionScreen
    testScreen = StringProperty('Screen1')

    def screenSelector(self)
        screenList = ['Screen1', 'Screen2']
        testNumber = random.randint(0, 1)
        testScreen = screenList[testNumber]
        return testscreen
```

I then want to choose this screen in my .kv-file, which looks somewhat like this, but also includes screen 1 and 2

```
ScreenManager:
    SelectionScreen:
        name: 'SelectionScreen'
    Screen0:
        name: 'Screen0'
    Screen1:
        name: 'Screen1'

<SelectionScreen>:
     BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click when ready"
            size_hint: .6, .5
            font_size: 10
            on_press: root.screenSelector()
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'Screen0'
<Screen0>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "Next"
            on_release: root.manager.current = str(root.testScreen)
```

The SelectionScreen is working fine, but now I am not able to reach screen0. When removing the line

```
on_press: root.screenSelector()
```

I can, however, do this.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

1. You are not able to reach ***screen0*** because it is not in your ***screenList***.
2. The variable, ***testScreen*** defined in method ***screenSelector*** is a local variable, which is not the same class variable, *testScreen* defined in class *selectionScreen*.
3. Undefined variable, *return* ***testscreen*** due to typo error.
4. At *Screen0*, the code, *on_release: root.manager.current = str(root.testScreen)* will cause an ***AttributeError: 'Screen0' object has no attribute 'testScreen'***

## Solution

In order to reach Screen0, you have to do the following:

### Python Script

1. Add ***Screen0*** into the variable, ***screenList***
2. Replace ***random.randint(0, 1)*** with ***random.randint(0, 2)***
3. Replace ***testScreen*** with ***self.testScreen*** in method *screenSelector*

### kv file

1. Define an id, e.g. ***id: selection_screen***
2. Reference it, e.g. ***root.manager.ids.selection_screen.testScreen***
3. Add on_press call to ***screenSelector*** in the other screens, e.g. ***on_press: root.manager.ids.selection_screen.screenSelector()***

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import random


class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class SelectionScreen(Screen):
    testScreen = StringProperty('Screen1')

    def screenSelector(self):
        screenList = ['Screen0', 'Screen1', 'Screen2']
        testNumber = random.randint(0, 2)
        self.testScreen = screenList[testNumber]
        return self.testScreen


class Screen0(Screen):
    pass


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<ScreenManager>:
    SelectionScreen:
        id: selection_screen
        name: 'SelectionScreen'
    Screen0:
        name: 'Screen0'
    Screen1:
        name: 'Screen1'
    Screen2:
        name: 'Screen2'

<SelectionScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Click when ready"
            size_hint: .6, .5
            font_size: 10
            on_press: root.screenSelector()
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = str(root.manager.ids.selection_screen.testScreen)

<Screen0>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "Screen 0"
            on_press: root.manager.ids.selection_screen.screenSelector()
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = str(root.manager.ids.selection_screen.testScreen)

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "Screen 1"
            on_press: root.manager.ids.selection_screen.screenSelector()
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = str(root.manager.ids.selection_screen.testScreen)

<Screen2>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            text: "Screen 2"
            on_press: root.manager.ids.selection_screen.screenSelector()
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = str(root.manager.ids.selection_screen.testScreen)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Screen2 Displayed]
[image: Img03 - Screen0 Displayed]
[image: Img04 - Screen1 Displayed]
[image: Img05 - Screen2 Displayed]
[image: Img06 - Screen0 Displayed]